# Java Fails to Run H2o Sparkling Water, java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 9

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I am trying to run a Spark + H2o Sparkling Water project and am using Maven as my build tool.

Here are the versions for each package:

> ```
> <properties>
>     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
>     <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
>     <spark.version>2.3.1</spark.version>
>     <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
>     <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
> </properties>
> ```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a version: 9
    at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.parts$1(Properties.scala:184)
    at scala.util.PropertiesTrait$class.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:187)
    at scala.util.Properties$.isJavaAtLeast(Properties.scala:17)
```

I am using Java 8, so I don't know why it's giving me this error.

Edit: The rest of my dependencies in my POM file look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Sparkling Water -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ai.h2o</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkling-water-package_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.28.0.3-1-2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-repl_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**EDIT (SOLVED):** 
The issue is resolved when I use Spark version 2.4.5

Comment: The version 9 appears nowhere in the snippet of your POM file which you showed us, leaving me to suspect that the problem lies somewhere else in the POM.

Comment: ... and that the error could arise if you're actually running with Java-9 and maven or your application libraries are trying to find the version of Java which had changed its format from let's say `1.x` to `N` (e.g. 1.8 to 9). Using `mvn -version` might tell you more.

Comment: I've added the rest of my dependencies to the original post. I don't believe it uses Java 9 anywhere.

Comment: @sendmecode Out of curiosity, are you actually building this on Java 8 or are you just targetting Java 8 on a newer JDK?

Comment: I believe I'm building it on Java 8. In Intellij, I have my project SDK set to Java version 1.8.0.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and not just as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** The issue is resolved when I use Spark version 2.4.5